# Attempting to route a URL with a dot leads to 404 with webpack dev server

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

I'm using Webpack's [dev server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) for ease of local development.  I'm working on a single page app, so I've enabled `historyApiFallback`:

```
common.devServer = {
  outputPath: path.join(__dirname, 'www', outDir),
  historyApiFallback: true
};
```

However, whenever I try to browse to a url that contains a period (such as `/ui/alerts/map.postplay`), I get

> Cannot GET /ui/alerts/map.postplay

How can I convince webpack-dev-server to let me use these urls?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UPDATE: You can now just set `historyApiFallback` to:

```
historyApiFallback: {
  disableDotRule: true
}
```

(thanks to BenR for fixing this!)

The trouble lies not in `webpack-dev-server` but the `historyApiFallback` config itself (technically, Webpack uses [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback)).  There's a [known bug](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/issues/17) relating to URLs with periods.

You can update the config for `historyApiFallback` to rewrite all urls containing periods:

```
historyApiFallback: {
  rewrites: [
    {from: /\./, to: '/'}
  ]
}
```

Since this operates on `req.url`, you should be fine even if you're doing local dev on something other than `localhost` via the hosts file, etc.

Comment: You can now disable the dot rule when this results in problems for you: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#disabledotrule